# Will performance be hit if a kernel is too short?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

If I'm doing an element-by-element operation on a matrix `M`, say `M[i, j] *= (1 - M[i, j])`, is it fine to launch a thread for each element `(i, j)`? I'm just concerned at what point the overhead of launching threads outweighs the parallelism achieved.

Comment: I thought GPU threads are not really threads

Comment: Have you benchmarked it yet?

Comment: Cuda Best Practices Guide is a good lecture to read. Answer by alrikai is good, it all depends on the application type, number of used registers, memory latencies etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's oftentimes a better idea to try to do more work per thread if possible, with the goal of having instruction-level parallelism. If a given thread executes multiple, independant operations, the instructions can be pipelined and executed without stalls, which will increase your arithmetic throuput. In contrast, if you have each thread doing 1 piece of (trivial) work, then there's no opportunity for any sort of instruction-level parallelism and no opportunity to hide any of your memory latency times.

Also, there's a finite number of registers available, so the more threads you launch with, the fewer the number of register available per thread. I'm not sure about Kepler cards, but back in the Fermi-card generation, registers had roughly 8x the bandwidth of shared memory, so using registers when possible was important (again, I don't have a kepler card, so I don't know if this has since changed).

Although it's a bit dated, the recommendations detailed [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/volkov10-GTC.pdf) are still very relevant